# Setting time-to-live to messages in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration, messaging, qpid

i need to set a time-to-live to my messages.

I tried the following example, but the time-to-live will be ignored. :/

context.xml

```
<int:channel id="publishChannel"/>

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter 
         channel="publishChannel" 
         destination="defaultDestination"
         time-to-live="5000" 
         pub-sub-domain="false" />
```

Publisher

```
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Publisher;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("publishService")
public class PublishService{
    private MessageChannel messageChannel;

    @Publisher(channel = "publishChannel")
    public Message<?> sendMessage (Message<?> message) {
        return message;
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According `JmsTemplate` JavaDocs we have:

```
/**
 * Set the time-to-live of the message when sending.
 * <p>Since a default value may be defined administratively,
 * this is only used when "isExplicitQosEnabled" equals "true".
 * @param timeToLive the message's lifetime (in milliseconds)
 * @see #isExplicitQosEnabled
 * @see javax.jms.Message#DEFAULT_TIME_TO_LIVE
 * @see javax.jms.MessageProducer#send(javax.jms.Message, int, int, long)
 */
public void setTimeToLive(long timeToLive) {
    this.timeToLive = timeToLive;
}
```

So, it doesn't work if `explicitQosEnabled` isn't `true` (`JmsTemplate#doSend`):

```
if (isExplicitQosEnabled()) {
    producer.send(message, getDeliveryMode(), getPriority(), getTimeToLive());
}
```

Hence you should add `explicit-qos-enabled="true"` alongside with `time-to-live="5000"` for your `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>`.